# Error code 415 when forwarding a POST from an api to another

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, post

I'm sending an application/json type from the postman client to a java API that forwards all the requests to the specific API for that case.
On this concrete case, I have a login API and I want to center code heard this JSON:

**JSON from the postman**

```
{
    "name": "random name",
    "password": "random passwd"
}
```

**The API that does the forward**

```
@RequestMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public String redirectHttpRequest(HttpServletRequest request, @Value("${endpoint}") String newURL,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

    try {

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String result = null;


        String body = IOUtils.toString(request.getReader());

        if (request.getMethod().equals("GET")) {
            // result = restTemplate.getForObject(redirectUrl.toString(), String.class);
        } else if (request.getMethod().equals("POST")) {
            result = restTemplate.postForObject(newURL, body, String.class);

        }
        return result;

    } catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        return "OLA";
    }

}
```

That new URL is the URL were the other API is (which, in this case, is `localhost:8080` and is from the `application.properties` file).

[image]

I've tested the login API through postman and it works, but when I try to connect it to that forward API I got the following error:

> org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 415 null.

I would like to know what I am doing wrong or an alternative way to do it.

**Postman call**
[image]

**Second endpoint code**
[image]

**The value of the body passed to the second endpoint**
[image]

**The User class**

public class User {

```
private String name;

private String password;

private List<String> groups;

public User(String name, String password) {
    this.name = name;
    this.password = password;
    this.groups = new ArrayList<String>();
}

public User() {

}

public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return this.password;
}

public List<String> getGroups() {
    return this.groups;
}

public String toString() {
    return "User: " + this.name + "\nGroups: " + this.groups;
}
```

Comment: For clarification purpose, are both endpoints on the same server? `localhost:8080` in your case?

Comment: No, they are on different servers. One is on 8080 and the other on 8082

Comment: So first one on `localhost:8082` and second one one `localhost:8080`? Same server, but different port

Comment: The one that does the forward is on localhost:8082/forward and the login one is on the localhost:8080/login. I can do a get request between the two of them but not a post and i dont know why.

Comment: Can you add to your post the values that are in `body` and `newURL` at the moment of the `postForObject` call, to make sure they look correct

Comment: 415 is `Unsupported Media Type`. What type is your login endpoint consuming?

Comment: I put the image on my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are getting the `415` error code. That means that your `/login` endpoint is not expecting the payload type you are sending him, see [here](https://restfulapi.net/http-status-codes/)

> 415 (Unsupported Media Type)
>
> The 415 error response indicates that the API is not able to process the client’s supplied media type, as indicated by the Content-Type request header. For example, a client request including data formatted as application/xml will receive a 415 response if the API is only willing to process data formatted as application/json.
>
> For example, the client uploads an image as image/svg+xml, but the server requires that images use a different format.

I think is this because when you call `postForObject`, you are not telling the media type of your payload. So instead of sending the json String alone, you need to wrap it into an `HttpEntity` that holds the body and also a header that specifies the media type of the payload you are forwarding. Try this out:

```
...
} else if (request.getMethod().equals("POST")) {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE);
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);
    result = restTemplate.postForObject(newURL, entity, String.class);
}
...
```

Comment: The error still appears, the body has the body that my post has, the new url is the url that the login api is running, which is http://localhost:8080/login, do u want a print of the body String? Both of them consume  MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE

Comment: can you try to change the body to `{"name":"random name", "password":"random passwd"}`

Comment: i have put my postman information to on my question,was that what you want?

Comment: I mean the JSON string you are using in your body: `{ name:"random name", password"random passwd" }`  is not valid JSON, so that might be the problem. So I'd like you try with a valid JSON string : `{"name":"random name", "password":"random passwd"}`

Comment: I put my string body with the info that you provided and it still doesnt work, same error.The second parameter of the postForObject is the information that i want to consume on the other api right?

Comment: Do you want print from the controller of the login api?

Comment: Your current code works for me, I tried it and it forwards. Yes you can add the `/login` endpoint code to your question. The only issue I can see is the invalid JSON

Comment: i already put the image, is the last one.What JSON did you use?

Comment: No, i think its the same, im going to put that as well on my question just to check.The controller is correct right?

Comment: maybe your second endpoint should say that it returns json, `produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE`

Comment: @pedroalmeida I do not understand the image with the controller in your postman, is your endpoint returning all that? Please add the code of the `/login` endpoint

Comment: the /login endpoint returns a user if valid and a responseEntity if not

Comment: @pedroalmeida I do not understand why you see the Java code in postman. You should only have the returned JSON there

Comment: there is any java code on the postman, they are different images, click on them and you will see.The json message returns an error  that i catch on my code

Comment: Oh ok! my bad :)

Comment: sorry about the mess, im still learning how to properly use this tools.I really dont know were is the problem, i really dont

Comment: Can you also add the definition of the `User` class (as code please, not as an image)

Comment: Sure i can but i doubt that the problem is there, because the login api works, i have tested it individually and even connected it to my frontend

Comment: @pedroalmeida Hi, I updated my answer, give it a go, it worked for me.

Comment: @pedroalmeida Cool, please upvote and accept my answer :)